# stock status not showing in product's page in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I have added a theme into my store after which everything is working fine but Instock status msg stops showing.Out of stock status is showing perfectly.

Could any one please suggest me where the problem exists?
Thanks

Comment: I enabled everything required:-

Answer (score 1):

The code has probably been removed from your theme's template. Where this code lies will depend on your version of Magento.

In Magento 1.7 this files is located at:

```
app/deisgn/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml
```

contains:

```
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
    <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?>     <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

this would be missing in the new theme version of your file at:

```
app/deisgn/frontend/default/[THEMENAME]/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml
```

Older versions of magento will have the code in a slightly different file, just search for it :)